# Python 3 Tkinter messagebox replication loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've recently started getting into python and writing some simple programs, and through stack overflow and YouTube tutorials its been pretty smooth sailing. However when I tried make a Tkinter "WM_DELETE_WINDOW" protocol and ran the program. The text box would open as normal and it would close properly with the quit text box, but then a second empty text box along with a second quit text box would open with the same message. Then after i closed that the program would try to destroy the box a third time and get this error.

```
C:\Users\thech\Desktop\Python stuff>python spam.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spam.py", line 34, in <module>
    spam()
  File "spam.py", line 31, in spam
    if closed():
  File "spam.py", line 13, in closed
    mibox.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\thech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2062, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you would look over my code, here it is:

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

#pop up
def spam():

    global spamreturn
    spamreturn = False

    def closed():
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
            mibox.destroy()
            return True

    mibox = Tk()
    topframe = Frame(mibox)
    miLabel = Label(mibox, text="Call 1-800-273-8255")
    mibutton = Button(topframe, text="Your Computer has been infected")
    mibutton2 = Button(topframe, text="Please call 1-800-273-8255 for Assistance")
    miLabel.pack()
    mibutton.pack()
    mibutton2.pack()
    topframe.pack()
    mibox.geometry("300x100+500+250")

    mibox.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closed)

    mibox.mainloop()

    if closed():
        spamreturn = True

spam()

if spamreturn == True:
    print("worked")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Just remove/comment out the `if closed():` and `spamreturn = True` and will work as desired
it causes the closed() function to execute again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem: when the user clicks the X button, the function `closed` is called automatically through the operating system.  Tkinter (and other GUI systems as well) have the property that your program is driven by user actions that create "events," which result in your "event handlers" getting called for you by the environment.  In your case, your function `closed` is a handler and the event is clicking on the X.

When your code gets to the function `mainloop` it doesn't return immediately.  Instead the program waits for user events.  When one of those user events results in the tk root object getting destroyed (that's `mibox.destroy()` in your case), the call to mainloop returns at that instant.  Here you again call `closed()`.  That results in the dialog box appearing a second time.  The tk environment has to open an empty tk window to have something to attach this dialog box to.  That's why you see a second dialog and a second window.  The problem is that explicit call to closed().

I modified your program and it now works.  I also made a couple of other changes.  I moved the global variable declaration to the outermost indent level - I don't like to create globals inside of functions, it makes the code too hard to follow.  You need a global statement inside the `closed` function; otherwise Python makes a local variable of the same name instead of modifying the global.  I also print the value of the global at the end whether it's true or not.

If this doesn't work just call 1-800-273-8255 for assistance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

spamreturn = False

#pop up
def spam():

    def closed():
        global spamreturn
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
            spamreturn = True
            mibox.destroy()

    mibox = Tk()
    topframe = Frame(mibox)
    miLabel = Label(mibox, text="Call 1-800-273-8255")
    mibutton = Button(topframe, text="Your Computer has been infected")
    mibutton2 = Button(topframe, text="Please call 1-800-273-8255 for Assistance")
    miLabel.pack()
    mibutton.pack()
    mibutton2.pack()
    topframe.pack()
    mibox.geometry("300x100+500+250")

    mibox.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", closed)

    mibox.mainloop()

spam()

print(spamreturn)
```